# How to fix lag issue over time in my Three.js game

Tags: javascript, three.js

When my game in Three.js starts, there is no lag. Over time however, computers that run this start to slow down over a five minute period. I can't figure out why this is though.

Iv'e already tried looking though my code and checking my arrays. I started changing some values to see if that was the problem, but nothing I've tried has worked!

```
// cloud spawning

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){

makeCloud()

}

// skeleton spawning

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){

    makeSkeleton()

}


// render

function render() {

      // animation  

       requestAnimationFrame(render);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // skybox position update

    skybox.position.set(player.position.x + 125, player.position.y + 125, player.position.z + 125)


    // camera positioning
    camera.position.set(player.position.x, player.position.y - 1, player.position.z)

    camera.position.z += 5 * Math.cos(playerDegree * Math.PI / 180);

        camera.position.x -= 5 * Math.sin(playerDegree * Math.PI / 180);
        camera.position.y += 3


    // function calling
    move()

    turn()

    jumpOn()

    gravity()

    cameraDistance()

    addBarrier(rock)

    addBarrier(bush)

    correctPlayer()

    energyGain()


}
render()

// distance function

function distance(x1, y1,z1,x2,y2,z2){

   let one = square(x1-x2)

   let two = square(y1-y2)

   let three = square(z1 - z2)

 let d= Math.sqrt(one+two+ three);

 return d;

 }
// squaring function

 function square(input){

   let output = input * input

   return output;

 }


// camera to rock distance function

 function cameraDistance(){

if (distance(camera.position.x, camera.position.y,  camera.position.z,

     rock.position.x,    rock.position.y,   rock.position.z) < 5){
rockMaterial.transparent = true

}else{

    rockMaterial.transparent = false

}}


// collision

   function collision(obj1, obj2){

    if(obj1.position.x + obj1.scale.x > obj2.position.x &&

            obj1.position.x < obj2.position.x + obj2.scale.x &&

            obj1.position.y + obj1.scale.y > obj2.position.y &&

            obj1.position.y < obj2.position.y + obj2.scale.y &&

            obj1.position.z + obj1.scale.z > obj2.position.z &&
            obj1.position.z < obj2.position.z + obj2.scale.z                     ){
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}


// barrier function

   function addBarrier(obj){

if (collision(player, obj)){


    //xpos pos barrier


    if (player.position.x > obj.position.x && 
    !player.position.y + player.scale.y > obj.position.y){

        player.position.x += playerSpeed

        console.log("xpos pos push")

    }else

    // xpos neg barrier

    if (player.position.x + player.scale.x < obj.position.x && 
    !player.position.y + player.scale.y > obj.position.y){

player.position.x -= playerSpeed

        console.log("xpos neg push")
    }else

    //zpos pos barrier

    if (player.position.z > obj.position.z && 
    !player.position.y + player.scale.y > obj.position.y){

        player.position.z += playerSpeed

        console.log("zpos pos push")
    }else

    // zpos neg barrier

    if (player.position.z + player.scale.z < obj.position.z && 
    !player.position.y + player.scale.y > obj.position.y){
        player.position.z -= playerSpeed
        console.log("zpos neg push")
    }else

    // ypos barrier

    if (player.position.y + player.scale.y >= obj.position.y &&  player.position.y <= obj.position.y + player.scale.y  && 
        player.position.x >= obj.position.x && player.position.x <= obj.position.x + obj.scale.x &&             
        player.position.z >= obj.position.z && player.position.z <= obj.position.z + obj.scale.z){


        //groundedObject = true
        //grounded = true
        console.log("top stay")

    }
    }
}


// cloud function

function makeCloud(){

    let bool;

 bool = (Math.random()*1000) + (Math.random()*-1000)

let cloudGeom1 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 5, Math.random() * 30)

let cloudGeom2 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 5, Math.random() * 30)

let cloudGeom3 = new THREE.CubeGeometry(Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 5, Math.random() * 30)

let cloudMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff, transparent: true})

let cloudMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeom1, cloudMat)

let cloudMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeom2, cloudMat)

let cloudMesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeom3, cloudMat)


let cloudMesh = new THREE.Group()

cloudMesh.add(cloudMesh1)

cloudMesh.add(cloudMesh2)

cloudMesh.add(cloudMesh3)


cloudMesh1.position.set(Math.random() * -10, Math.random() * 10 + 30, Math.random() * -100)

cloudMesh2.position.set(Math.random() * -10, Math.random() * 10 + 30, Math.random() * -100)

cloudMesh3.position.set(Math.random() * -10, Math.random() * 10 + 30, Math.random() * -100)

cloudMesh.position.set(Math.random() * bool, Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * bool)


scene.add(cloudMesh)

cloudArray.push(cloudMesh)

}


// correct player to random terrain height function


function correctPlayer(){

    for(i = 0; i < groundArray.length; i++){

if(collision(player, groundArray[i])|| player.position.y - player.scale.y <= groundArray[i].position.y){

    grounded = true


}else{
    grounded = false

}}}


// make a skeleton

function makeSkeleton(){

var skeletonArray = [] 



  // skeleton geometries
   let skeletonGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,2,1)

   let skeletonRightEyeG = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.1,0.2,0.2) 

   let skeletonLeftEyeG = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.1,0.2,0.2)

   let skeletonMouthAG = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.1,0.1,0.4)

  let skeletonMouthBG = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.1,0.2,0.1) 

//skeleton meshes

  let skeletonRightEye = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonRightEyeG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f})) 

  let skeletonLeftEye = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonLeftEyeG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f})) 

  let skeletonBody = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonGeometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff})) 

// skeleton materials ( not in use )

  let blackMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f})

  let skeletonMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff}) 

// more skeleton meshes

     let skeletonMouthA = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonMouthAG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f}))

     let skeletonMouthB = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonMouthBG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f}))

     let skeletonMouthC = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonMouthBG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f}))

     let skeletonMouthD = new THREE.Mesh(skeletonMouthBG, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0f0f0f}))



      // skeleton group

      let skeleton = new THREE.Group() 

      skeleton.add(skeletonBody),

       skeleton.add(skeletonRightEye) 

       skeleton.add(skeletonLeftEye) 

       skeleton.add(skeletonMouthA) 

       skeleton.add(skeletonMouthB) 

       skeleton.add(skeletonMouthC)

       skeleton.add(skeletonMouthD) 


      // skeleton potitioning

      skeletonBody.position.x = 10 

      skeletonBody.position.y = 2 

      skeletonLeftEye.position.set(9.5, 2.5, 0.3)

       skeletonRightEye.position.set(9.5, 2.5, -0.3)

       skeletonMouthA.position.set(9.5, 2.0, 0),

    skeletonMouthB.position.set(9.5, 2.0, -0.133)
,
    skeletonMouthC.position.set(9.5, 2.0, 0),

    skeletonMouthD.position.set(9.5, 2.0, 0.133)

skeleton.position.set(Math.random() * 150,  skeletonBody.scale.y, Math.random() * -150)


        skeleton.rotation.y = (Math.PI / 2) * -2;

        scene.add(skeleton)

        skeletonArray.push(skeleton)


}
```

My expected results after changing values of arrays and making the map smaller was that the lag issue would stop.

My actual results was just lag.

Comment: in the future, try to keep all code inside the code block and avoid pasting entire programs

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome's developer tools to check memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, try to keep your code readable and concise. Preferably organized in small chunks. It makes it a lot easier for others to read and, consequently, to help you. Also, indent and use semi-colons `;` Although not necessary, they improve readability as well.

---

With that out of the way, let me try to explain what could be the reason behind your problem.

So, your code is not complete. There are some missing pieces of it, making it even harder to debug. But I believe this is a memory leak problem, you seem to be adding too many objects to the scene without ever removing them.

Inside your main update function `render()`, that gets called every frame, you are adding barriers indefinitely. This causes lag, because you are only filling the scene and the memory with more and more information, without every clearing some of those objects.

You need to keep track of the objects in the scene, remove them from the scene and call `.dispose()` whenever they aren't needed anymore. This should help with lag.

But it's impossible to know for sure without more information on the problem. Try editing your original post with missing info, making it more readable, and I'll gladly edit this answer